# codeigniter security issue when inserting % value to database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-injection

i have really interesting problem.

i have text box, button(add to database) and user input something like that:

%100 pay,%45 pay,no pay.....

the problem is results are different from user inputs. i think codeigniter clear something.

input: %100 pay,%75 pay,no pay
result:0 pay,%75 pay,no pay

%100 pay becomes 0 pay but %75 pay keeps original value.

it doesnt accept 1 and % combined.

```
$this->db->insert('payment',$array);
```

Comment: `codeigniter security issue when inserting %` Which security issue?, BTW a make a test to `insert` and `select` similar data, but no errors found.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CodeIgniter will remove characters in the input data that it considers dangerous. This filter is applied to `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`. You can use `$_REQUEST` to work around that.